# DirectX или OpenGL

Tags: directx, opengl

Как можно подойти к `DirectX`, чтоб его понять? Изучал `OpenGL` очень легкий, но широких возможностей я не встречал. Видел как на `DirectX` сделали (в `Microsoft`) рендер моря. И думаю, что такое не возможно на `OpenGL`. Что лучше выбрать, то что я лучше понимаю или биться и понять `DirectX`?

Comment: [Статья на Хабре](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/gdev/123194/)

Comment: в програмах не приходится использовать ни то ни другое. но когда вспыла информация что microsoft для отрисовки гуи использует opengl я для себя определился

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Первые версии OpenGL действительно очень лёгкие. Но из-за некоторых вещей страдает производительность. Например glBegin()glVertex()glEnd() намного медленнее, чем использование буфера вершин. В Директе этого нет, в новых версиях OpenGL это вырезали. Поэтому современный OpenGL не легче, чем Direct3D. Главным плюсом OpenGL является кроссплатформенность. Ещё OpenGL не сразу поддерживается в драйверах. Иногда в нём бывают баги, потому что он менее распространён, чем DX.
 Преимущество DirectX в том, что он состоит из нескольких частей. Direct3D - это только его отдельная часть. Ещё есть DirectSound, DirectMusic для звука, DirectInput для ввода. Хотя эти компоненты можно спокойно использовать в OpenGL приложении (только оно из-за этого перестанет быть кроссплатформенным). В DirectX ещё есть удобная отладка. Ещё с DX поставляется библиотека D3DX, одной из очень удобных функций которой является возможность загружать текстуры некоторых форматов. В OpenGL такого нет, надо самостоятельно загружать текстуры, зная двоичный формат файла, хотя можно найти вспомогательные библиотеки.
 Но несмотря на всё это, я выбрал OpenGL, так как планирую сделать свой движок кроссплатформенным.

Comment: Следовательно... Лучше выбрать DirectX?)

Comment: Я думаю, что по этим причинам все игры пишут на DirectX. Но лично я всё-равно выбрал OpenGL.

Answer (score 4):

Изучайте OpenGL 3.3 и выше. Современный OpenGL почти не уступает по своим возможностям DirectX.

Comment: Это хорошо что ни чем не уступает и все таки она легче. Не знаешь как можно произвести инициализацию что бы не было консольного окна?

Comment: Если не ошибаюсь про это можно прочитать в "супер книге" по OpenGL. Там подробно обсуждается тема портирования OpenGL на Windows.

Comment: Консольное окно появлется потому, что вы создаёте консольное приложение. Но я бы на вашем месте от него не избавлялся: оно полезно для дебажного аутпута. А убрать его всегда успеете.

Answer (score 3):

Документация по Direct X написана лучше. В MSDN рассматривается сама суть построения трехмерной сцены с нуля. Авторы документации OpenGl подразумевают что вы уже знаете как использовать матрицы для афинных преобразований, что такое нормальны векторы, мипмаппинг, вертексные и фрагментные шейдеры, как работает конвейер, как накладываются текстуры  и поэтому просто в алфавитном порядки описывают заголовки функций которые есть в библиотеке.

По поводу рендера моря в OpenGl то это значительно проще в поздних версиях, так как в них шейдеры пишутся на С подобном языке, а не на ассемблере видеокарты.

А вообще для программного построения годной трехмерной сцены нужно хорошо знать математику(матрицы, кватернионы для вращения, интегралы Френеля для расчета света) а не какую-то конкретную библиотеку.

Answer (score 2):

Смотря для каких задач, OpenGL дает путь к кросплатформенной разработке, и возможность легко перейти в геймдев под мобильные платформы iOS/Android, что в данный момент довольно востребовано. С другой стороны DirectX дает более мощное API, и если речь идет о разработке игр/приложений исключительно под Win-платформу, то лучше писать на DX. А в современном, взрослом PC-шном геймдеве, DX по сути, стандарт.
К тому же DX и выглядит и работает быстрее, хотя все зависит от прямоты рук разработчиков (сравнивал игры L4D2 и TF2, на одном и том же компе под MacOS и Win7).

В общем на любителя, начать изучение 3D лучше с того, что больше нравится, потом всегда успеешь переквалифицироваться под то, что будет нужнее. А начать можешь с рисования кубика-рубика на OGL и DX. Сам поймешь что удобнее для тебя.

Answer (score 1):

OpenGL - это штука, которая нужна для распространения твоей графики практически на всем, но в нем (для меня) не удобно работать. Это скорее всего из-за того, что разработчики этой либы долго тянули в свое время кота за хвост, и это теперь дает о себе знать.

---

1)практически объектно-неориентирован; 2)DirectX3D легче понимается структура самой библиотеки, пробовал изучать OpenGL, очень много вопросов для самоучки прямо налету, справка онлайн тоже не очень.
Так что лично я создаю свое приложение на DirectX и С#, а потом когда все будет готово, буду потихоньку переводить код на эту не так развитую, но очень востребованную OpenGL/OpenGL ES для кросс-платформы вместе с C++ (Qt).